# Asp core middleware invoking multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I created a custom middleware in my asp core application

```cs
public class RxtraClientToServerEncryptionKeyGetMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public RxtraClientToServerEncryptionKeyGetMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    } 

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, 
        RxtraClientToServerEncryptionKeyGetSetHandler handler)
    {
        await handler.HandelRequest(context);
        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

and calling this middleware in the startup file

```cs
app.UseMiddleware<RxtraAuthCookieAuthentication>();
app.UseMiddleware<RxtraClientToServerEncryptionKeySetMiddleware>();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseMiddleware<RxtraClientToServerEncryptionKeyGetMiddleware>();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "pagename",
        pattern: "{pagename}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Page", action = "Index" });
});
```

Now if I run the application, then System will call this middleware first then my controller.

```cs
public class HomeController: Controller
{ 
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Home()
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and call index view then **I don't know why but again going for custom middleware and calling it again**

but in my controller. if if return  **return Ok(true);** instead of **view()** then this custom middleware only calls one time.

I don't understand why this is happening?

Comment: Middleware is bi-directional are you sure this isn't by design behavior?

Comment: @asawyer But how can I ensure that system will call this middleware only one time. Because I have some in this middleware which should only run once

Comment: check for 404 on images or any type of resource maybe a part of your app is issuing a request looking for a missing resource

Comment: @HMZ Got the point. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @sourabhdevpura glad to help

Comment: Hello friend, did we ever find a solution?